# Function not defined error in angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have a grid like this ,

```
 this.columns=
[
     {
        text: 'S.No', columntype: 'textbox', filtertype: 'input', datafield: 'id', width: 50, cellsalign: 'center'
    },
    {
        text: 'Edit, columntype: 'textbox', datafield: 'id', width: 50, cellsrenderer =Action
    }

]

var Action = function (row, columnfield, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties) {

    return '<button onClick="done()">edit</button>'
 }

my function ,

done () {
     alert('hi')
 }
```

Error: done is not defined.

I am really having hard time solving this.I used jqwidgets. Can anyone please help.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the angular 2 directive for the click event:

```
var Action = function (row, columnfield, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties) {

    return '<button (click)="done()">edit</button>'
 }
```

And I am not sure, if your code works like this. Usually you have an component template.

Comment: Then your code is wrong. See this simple example in the documentation (scroll down to the full component code): https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html